# Proper way to get the value of Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, radio-button

I thought this was going to work, but it doesn't return false if empty. Any Suggestions?

```
var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("Vehicle");
for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
    console.log("radioButton " + i + ": " + radioButtons[i].value);
}
}
```

Source: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?679670-RESOLVED-How-to-use-Javascript-to-get-the-value-of-a-radio-button

Comment: do you have any question?

Comment: would you please repost it as question-answer form?!!

Comment: I thought this was going to work, but it doesn't return false if empty

Answer (score 1):

Because all radio buttons with mutually exclusive selection has the same `name`....and no two elements should have the same `id`. And getting using `id`s of all buttons is tedious.